# Order by and Index on a Join mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named "MI_APR". I am bringing in data from a "calendar" table using a LEFT JOIN. This data being transferred is a column of DATES with column name "First_Date".

```
ALTER TABLE MI_APR
    ADD COLUMN `Profile` CHAR(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'MI',
    ADD COLUMN First_Date DATE,
    CHANGE `Location Label` `Label`TINYTEXT;

    UPDATE MI_APR LEFT JOIN calendar on MI_APR.`Period` = calendar.`Unique_Period`
    SET
    MI_APR.`First_Date` = calendar.`First_Date`
```

After the join has happened, I need some help sorting the "FIRST_DATE" column in ASC , which is a simple date column in format YYYY-MM-DD.
I then need to add a new column named INDEX, that has values starting from 0 for the earliest month, counting upwards, based on the Month number in that DATES column in the MI_APR table. The index will run continue to run upwards even across years. See example below :

```
EXPECTED OUTPUT
    FIRST_DATE    INDEX
    2018/10/01    0
    2018/11/01    1
    2018/12/01    2
    2019/01/01    3
```

Thank you

Comment: If you are sorting it's a select not an update, right ?

Comment: @DanielE Yes I am assuming a select should be used somewhere however not sure how to add it in this case. I need the ordering of the column to happen only after then join, since the DATES column is only present after the join has happened.

Comment: @DanielE Also I would like the table to be sorted and then updated tor reflect this new sort order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either calculate your index on the fly with this query:

```
SELECT First_Date, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, earliest_date, First_Date) AS Index
FROM MI_APR
, (SELECT First_Date AS earliest_date FROM MI_APR ORDER BY First_Date ASC LIMIT 1) fancy_alias;
```

If the result pleases you, you can transform it into an update. My advice is though, that you shouldn't store data, which can easily be calculated on the fly!

```
UPDATE MI_APR
, (SELECT First_Date AS earliest_date FROM MI_APR ORDER BY First_Date ASC LIMIT 1) fancy_alias
SET `Index` = TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, earliest_date, First_Date);
```

Regarding your comment "Also I would like the table to be sorted and then updated".
There is no order in a table you can rely on. If you want a result from a select sorted, use the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: the earliest date do I need to manually type a date value in here ? I would like the formulas to dynamically select the earliest date from the DATES column

Comment: No, that's an alias for the column, as can be seen here: `, (SELECT First_Date AS earliest_date...`. It reads the earliest date from your table.

Comment: ok I tried but I am getting an error for the update statement, also select statement same error
ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Index = TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, earliest_date, First_Date)' at line 3

Comment: Index is a keyword, either use a better column name or put it in backticks. Edited my answer accordingly.